# Mean average of exponential functions

Tags: summation, exponential-function, average

I'm new to math stack exchange. Hope this goes well!

So, I have a set of exponential functions each defined in the form
\begin{aligned}
f_i(x)=a_ie^{-b_ix}+c_i
\end{aligned}
where $(a_i, b_i, c_i) \in \Bbb R^+$. (EDIT: Changed from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^+$)

Is it correct to say that:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x) &= (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)e^{-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i)x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i
\end{aligned}

for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$?

If so, how can we prove it?
If not, why not?

Comment: Quick counterexample: $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Hmmm... So if alternating between negative and positive values of $b_i$ doesn't work, should I change the question so that it only includes positive values of $a_i,b_i,c_i$?

Comment: Are you sure you want your sums to start at $i=0$ so they have $n+1$ terms? Why, then, divide them by $n$?

Comment: That was silly of me. I forgot that sums are upper and lower bound inclusive with their indices :facepalm:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote :

> \begin{aligned}
> f_i(x)=a_ie^{-b_ix}+c_i
> \end{aligned}
>   where $(a_i, b_i, c_i) \in \Bbb R^+$. 
>   Is it correct to say that:
>   \begin{aligned}
> \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}f_i(x) &= (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i)e^{-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i)x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i
> \end{aligned}

First there is a mistake : A sum from $i=0$ to $i=n$ counts $n+1$ terms, not $n$.

So, for average, you should write $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}$ or $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ ,but not $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}$ .

I suppose that it is a typo and that the proposed relationship is 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_ie^{-b_ix}+c_i)
 = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)e^{-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i)x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i$$

It is easy to find a lot of counter-examples .

For example, check your formula with

$$n=2\:;\:a_1=a_2=1\:;\:b_1=1\:;\:b_2=3\:;\:c _1=c_2=0$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_ie^{-b_ix}+c_i) =\frac12 (e^{-x}+e^{-3x})\\
(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)e^{-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i)x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i =e^{-2x}
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac12 (e^{-x}+e^{-3x})\neq e^{-2x}$$
Thus  $\quad \boxed{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x) = (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)e^{-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i)x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\quad \text{is false.}}$

Another obvious counter-example, with   $a_k=1\:;\:b_k=k\:;\: c_k=0$ :

$$\quad \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{-kx} \neq e^{-\frac{n+1}{2}x}$$
because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{-kx}=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{n(1-e^{-x})}\neq e^{-\frac{n+1}{2}x}$ .

Note that the proposed relationship is true in the trivial case $b_1=b_2=…=b_n$ .

Comment: Ok, so does this mean that if I changed my definition of $f_i(x)$ to $f_i(x) = a_ie^{bx}+c_i$, is it now true that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)=(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)e^{bx}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i$?

Comment: @Paydayzcool. Of course.